# How can an op-amp act as a precision diode?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, diodes

I read in an article on application of op-amp that it can act as a precision diode. Precision diode is an ideal diode having very much less forward voltage drop. I am not able to understand this concept. Please explain it to me.

Comment: The op-amp provides the Forward bias to the diode.

Answer (score 11):

An ideal op-amp wants to make its two inputs equal in voltage through the negative feedback path. Look at a very simple "precision diode":

[image: schematic]

Notice that the inverting input (-) is also Vout. Vin is the other input. Remember, the op-amp wants to make its inputs the same voltage.

Let's assume that Vout starts at 0V, and Vin is 5V. Because the inverting input is at a lower voltage than the non-inverting input, the output of the op-amp will be positive. This causes current to flow through the diode, to ground.

If this were just a diode, then we'd observe the usual 0.65-ish volt drop of the diode. But the op-amp still sees this difference. At the point where Vout is 0.65V less than Vin, there is still a difference between the op-amp's inputs, and consequently it will drive the output even higher, seeking equilibrium where the two inputs are the same voltage.

Eventually, the op-amp's output voltage is 0.65V *higher* than Vin. After the voltage drop, this makes Vout = Vin, and the op-amp's inputs are at the same voltage, and we have reached equilibrium.

Now Vout and Vin are at 5V, but say then Vin drops to 0V. The op-amp will now try to compensate by outputting the most negative voltage it can. However, the diode prevents any current flowing due to this negative voltage. Thus, it behaves as a diode, allowing current in only one direction, except with no voltage drop.

Comment: Only one remark... "An ideal op-amp wants to make its two inputs equal in voltage" but it can control only the voltage of the inverting input "through the negative feedback path"... the other voltage at the non-inverting input is controlled only by the input source. So the op-amp "wants" to (can) make the voltage of the inverting input equal to the voltage of the non-inverting input.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist exactly...except when it can't, because it's inhibited by the diode. That's what makes this a precision rectifier and not a voltage follower.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, an op-amp can act like a precision rectifier but not in power applications - if you have a signal that you want to rectify (maybe in order to convert to a peak value) then use the circuit below: -

[image]

The negative part of the signal is accurately reproduced as a positive going signal at Vout. Two op-amps can be combined to produce a full wave rectifier also.

This is not some form of perfect power rectification - its use is limited to low power signals.

There are simpler circuits that use one diode but, if you need to precision rectify a fairly high speed signal, you need to avoid saturating the amplifier when the "wrong" polarity half of the waveform is present - this is achieved with the extra diode (D2 in the diagram above).

Googling "[precision rectifier](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=precision+rectifier&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=piKtVJWFI47U7AayiYHwCQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1280&bih=897)" will get a few other suggestions on ideas.

Comment: Are "precision diode" and "precision rectifier" the same things?

Comment: @Pana as far as I'm concerned they are but don't quote me on it.

Answer (score 7):

**Series (non-inverting) diode limiter.** This is the simplest circuit of an "ideal diode" connected in series to the load RL (the load does not belong to the circuit):

[image]

In this circuit, the op-amp raises its output voltage with VF to overcome the undesired (here) forward diode voltage drop VF. Look also at this [Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Group_66a#Lab_4a:_How_to_make_perfect_circuits_by_series_NFB) to see how my students converted the imperfect diode into an almost ideal "diode" without VF... or click on the diode symbol in the library of the [animated story](http://www.circuit-fantasia.com/collections/tools/strange-things.html) below to investigate the circuit:

[image]

The disadvantages of this non-inverting circuit solution are the saturation (at the negative input half-wave) and the common-mode error. Then let's see another inverting implementation of an "ideal diode".

**Parallel (inverting) diode limiter.** This odd circuit resembles an op-amp log converter but here the op-amp output is not used as a conventional circuit output; instead, the inverting op-amp input serves as an output?!? Let's see why...

[image]

*At positive input voltage* (when the circuit limits), the op-amp adds a compensating voltage VOA = VF in series with the forward voltage drop VF across the diode. As a result, the combination of the imperfect diode and op-amp becomes an almost ideal *virtual diode* having zero forward voltage drop VF ≈ 0... and it behaves just as a piece of wire. The imperfect passive diode limiter (the resistor R and diode D) that would clip the input positive voltage at approximately 0.7V has transmuted into an almost ideal limiter clipping the voltage at ≈ 0V (virtual ground).

*At negative input voltage*, the op-amp reaches the positive rail... the diode is off... and the input voltage is applied through the resistor R to the load (obviously, R should be low enough).

**Generalization.** In both the "ideal diode" implementations - non-inverting (series) and inverting (parallel), the op-amp actually does the same - it adds a voltage (emf) VF in series to the voltage drop VF across the diode. The only difference is that in the first case, it raises with VF the voltage before the diode ("pulls up" the anode) while in the second case, it drops with VF the voltage after the diode ("pulls down" the cathode).

And as a final remark, if "diode" means "2-terminal element", then only the last topology can be considered as a diode. This *virtual element* consists of the diode D, the op-amp OA and the power supply -Vs (comprised by the orange balloon in the picture below). The result of all this combination is surprising - zero resistance and zero voltage across the "element"... just a piece of wire connected in parallel to (shorting) the load. The two terminals are the summing point (where the inverting input and the diode are connected) and the positive terminal of the negative supply -Vs.

[image]

Here is another [Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Group_68b#Lab_4:_How_to_make_perfect_components_by_parallel_NFB) where my students converted in this way the imperfect diode into an almost ideal "diode" without VF.

[image]